# Object not found in R.net c#

Tags: c#, r.net

After importing data from csv files, I want to arrange them according to Id numbers for example for the first table:

```
DataFrame DataIns = engine.Evaluate("DataIns<-read.table('C:/Users/isalah/Desktop/Fichiers_CRM/Fichier_csv/Diagnostic.csv', header=TRUE, sep =';',fill = TRUE)").AsDataFrame();
engine.Evaluate("DataIns[with(DataIns, order(Id)),]").AsExpression();
```

But this error was shown :

> 'Error in order(Id) : object 'Id' not found

how resolve it? thanks !

Comment: Just a quick guess... Missing single quotes around `Id`? `engine.Evaluate("DataIns[with(DataIns, order('Id')),]").AsExpression();`

Comment: @walther,thanks very much!!

Comment: Glad it helped, I just posted it as an answer so other people can see it more easily. Feel free to accept the answer so it's more clear it has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're missing single quotes around `Id`, so it tries to evaluate it as an object.

Correct way of doing it is like this:

```
engine.Evaluate("DataIns[with(DataIns, order('Id')),]").AsExpression();
```